# Hibernate: SQLGrammerException thrown on object insertion into Derby embedded database

Tags: java, hibernate, derby

I'm receiving this error from Hibernate whenever I try to insert an object into a table in a Derby embedded database:

```
Hibernate: insert into car (cost, make, model, price, sold, start, type, year, doors, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Aug 30, 2016 2:13:40 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 20000, SQLState: 42X01
Aug 30, 2016 2:13:40 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Syntax error: Encountered "year" at line 1, column 63.
Aug 30, 2016 2:13:40 PM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1403)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at com.ethanrich.dao.CarDAO.insert(CarDAO.java:27)
    at com.ethanrich.finalproject.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.buildBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.getBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2915)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3434)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1397)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "year" at line 1, column 63.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement42.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver42.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "year" at line 1, column 63.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatementOrSearchCondition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
```

Code:

Main.class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Model m = new Model();

        ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
        vehicles.add(new Car(2, "Toyota", "Camry", 2009, dateOf(2012, 7, 23), dateOf(2012, 7, 27), 7600.00, 17500.00, 4));


        for(Vehicle v : vehicles) {
            m.getCarDAO().insert((Car) v);
        }
    }

    public static Date dateOf(int year. int month, int day) {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
        return new Date(gc.getTimeInMillis());\
    }
}
```

Vehicle.class

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Vehicle {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private int year;
    private String type;
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private Date start; 
    private Date sold;
    private double cost;
    private double price;

    public Vehicle() {}
    public Vehicle(int id, String type, String make, String model, int year, Date start, Date sold, double cost, double price) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setType(type);
        this.setMake(make);
        this.setModel(model);
        this.setYear(year);
        this.setDateStart(start);
        this.setDateSold(sold);
        this.setCost(cost);
        this.setPrice(price);
    }

    // GETTERS

    public int getId() {return id;}
    public String getType() {return type;}
    public String getMake() {return make;}
    public String getModel() {return model;}
    public int getYear() {return year;}
    public Date getDateStart() {return start;}
    public Date getDateSold() {return sold;}
    public double getCost() {return cost;}
    public double getPrice() {return price;}

    // SETTERS

    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
    public void setType(String type) {this.type = type;}
    public void setMake(String make) {this.make = make;}
    public void setModel(String model) {this.model = model;}
    public void setYear(int year) {this.year = year;}
    public void setDateStart(Date start) {this.start = start;}
    public void setDateSold(Date sold) {this.sold = sold;}
    public void setCost(double cost) {this.cost = cost;}
    public void setPrice(double price) {this.price = price;}

}
```

Car.class

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car extends Vehicle {

    private int doors;

    public Car() {
        super();
    }

    public Car(int id, String make, String model, int year, Date start, Date sold, double cost, double price, int doors) {
        super(id, "CAR", make, model, year, start, sold, cost, price);
        this.setDoors(doors);
    }

    public int getDoors() {
        return doors;
    }

    public void setDoors(int doors) {
        this.doors = doors;
    }

    public String toString() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
        return "ID: #" + getId() + " Type: Car, " + getMake() + ", " + getModel() + ", car year is , start inventory date is " +  sdf.format(getDateStart()) + ", date sold " + sdf.format(getDateSold()) + ", dealer’s car cost is $" + getCost() + ", sold price is $" + getPrice() + ", 4 wheels.";
    }
}
```

CarDAO.class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery;

public class CarDAO {

    public static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public CarDAO(SessionFactory sf) {
        sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    public CarDAO(){}

    public void insert(Car c) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(c);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public void delete(Car c) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(c);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public void update(Car c) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(c);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public Car getById(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Car c = (Car) session.get(Car.class, id);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return c;
    }
}
```

Model.class

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.ethanrich.databeans.*;

public class Model {

    private TruckDAO truckDAO;
    private CarDAO carDAO;

    public Model() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Car.class); 

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

        carDAO = new CarDAO(sessionFactory);
    }

    public CarDAO getCarDAO() { return carDAO; }
    public void setCarDAO(CarDAO carDAO) { this.carDAO = carDAO;}

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer">allow</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
  <!--  -->
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby:vehicles;create=true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
  <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <!--  <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">ON_CLOSE</property> -->
  <mapping class="com.erisawesome.databeans.Vehicle"/>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The program simply takes the Car objects in an ArrayList and inserts them into the database.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the exception, it tells you the cause of the problem: "ERROR: Syntax error: Encountered "year" at line 1, column 63.". It happens that "year" is a reserved keyword in Derby, so you can not use it for table or column names.. change the name of the column and try again..

Check the reserved keywords in derby at https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefkeywords29722.html